# Can an NFT be owned by multiple people?

Tags: ether, nft, opensea

I am new to `Crypto` and `NFT` and was browsing the `OpenSea` platform for NFT's, for 1 `NFT` art it showed that it had 64 owners and a total of 100. I am wondering what that means, do 64 people own that piece of art, and are there 100 copies of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two broad standards of tokens trading on OpenSea - ERC721s and ERC1155s

[ERC721](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721) implements the `ownerOf` method:

```
function ownerOf(uint256 _tokenId) external view returns (address);
```

This suggests that an NFT can only be owned by one address. A nuance is that if this address points to a contract/multi-sig, one could argue that this NFT is owned by a group of persons.

What you're looking at is an [ERC1155](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1155) token that allows creation of Semi-Fungible tokens that can have multiple copies such as the one you've mentioned.

Comment: How to read on Etherscan's contract view who the multi-sigs of an address or NFT are?

Answer (score 0):

yes, it mean the NFT have 100 copy and out of which 64 are purchased.

Comment: How does that affect its price? Is an NFT with 1 copy more valuable than one with 100 copies?

Comment: Responding to the comment. "How does that affect its price? Is an NFT with 1 copy more valuable than one with 100 copies?" That all depends on supply, demand, hypes, trends etc... Think of a Banksy and numbered Banksy re-prints. Naturally, the re-prints are less valuable than the original. However a single copy NFT of some nice artwork I created can easily be much less valuable than an NFT of an NBA player card that has 1000 or more copies.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a way to split up a NFT between several owners:

https://medium.com/@arbenk/fractionalized-nft-f-nfts-all-that-you-need-to-know-46bc06ea486d

Comment: Hi Oli and welcome - could you provide additional details on your answer (ie not just a link which can unfortunately go down in the future)? Thank you:)